# Pass variable to a promised function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I call an async function that doesn't 'belong' to me inside a loop. I need to get retrieve a variable inside the 'then' function. Here is how I do it:

```
    for(var int = 0; int < attachments.length; int++) {
        dp.getAttachment(attachments[int]).then(function (response) {
            console.log(int);
        });
    }
```

How can I send the int so I can get it inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the wrong use of a [closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake).

Here since you have an array, you can create a local closure by using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over it

```
attachments.forEach(function (item, it) {
    dp.getAttachment(item).then(function (response) {
        console.log(int);
    });
})
```

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

Using the power of closures, you can ensure a copy of each value of the `int` variable is available when the `then` callback gets invoked.

```
for(var int = 0; int < attachments.length; int++) {
    (function(int) {
        dp.getAttachment(attachments[int]).then(function (response) {
            console.log(int);
        });
    })(int);
}
```